# How do I count two entries in one SQL Query in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have two columns in my ForumPost Table: `Id` and `ThreadId`.

I want to count all Entries in `Id` and `ThreadId` for a specific User:

#### Code snippet

```
cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = connection;
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT dbo.ForumPost.ThreadId, "
                    + "Id, "
                    + " COUNT(ForumPost.Id)AS PostCount AND (ForumPost.ThreadId)AS
                        ThreadCount"
                    + " FROM ForumPost "
                    + " WHERE UserName = @UserName ";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserName", ThreadUserName));
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (reader.HasRows)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        int postCount = Convert.ToInt16(reader["PostCount"]);
        int threadCount = Convert.ToInt16(reader["ThreadCount"]);
        AllPosts = postCount + threadCount;
    }
}
reader.Close();
```

Comment: What? Can you give a worked example with some sample data and what you want the result should be for that data?

Comment: You are going to need a `GROUP BY`, but without knowing what the columns represent, it is hard to say more.

Comment: You also don't need `HasRows` because a GROUP BY query always returns at least 1 row. If you got an error, you have bigger problems, so still don't need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a User can have different ThreadId count and Id count, you'll have to split that up into separate queries.

```
SELECT COUNT(Id) as PostCount, UserName
WHERE UserName = '@UserName'
GROUP BY Id, UserName


SELECT COUNT(ThreadId) as ThreadCount, UserName
WHERE UserName = '@UserName'
GROUP BY Id, UserName
```

Comment: If you're grouping by the same set of columns, you can combine the queries. Why would you do two queries when you can do one?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing a bit here, but I think you want a count of the number of posts the user has made and the number of different (distinct) threads that the user has participated in:

```
SELECT 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(Id)
        FROM ForumPost
        WHERE UserName = @UserName
    ) AS PostCount,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ThreadId)
        FROM ForumPost
        WHERE UserName = @UserName
    ) AS ThreadCount
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `COUNT(Column)` is going to count +1 for each row that has a non-null value in the `Column`. So if you `SELECT COUNT(Id) as PostCount, COUNT(ThreadId) as ThreadCount` you are likely going to get the same numbers in both counts, since you count how many rows have non-null `Id` and `ThreadId` respectively.

What is likely your intent is that you want to count how many posts in how many individual threads has the user posted, for this you can use `COUNT(DISTINCT Column)`:

```
cmd.CommandText = @"
   SELECT  COUNT(ForumPost.Id) AS PostCount 
      , COUNT(DISTINCT ForumPost.ThreadId) AS ThreadCount
   FROM ForumPost 
   WHERE UserName = @UserName ";
```

However, it is not clear what is your actual intent, since you're mixing this with retrieving the Id and the ThreadId too. You could mean that you want the total count of posts in each thread, the count of posts by this individual user in any thread he posted, or you want a list of posts *and* a total count (ie. two separate queries). You'll need to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT COUNT(ForumPost.Id)AS PostCount AND (ForumPost.ThreadId)AS ThreadCount" 
                                    // + " COUNT(ForumPost.ThreadId)AS ThreadCount " 
                                     + " FROM ForumPost " 
                                     + " WHERE UserName = @UserName ";
```

Your selecting of ID and ThreadID is causing a record to be returned for each which is why you're getting a double count.

Comment: Sorry, I did a quick cut/paste/delete on that one. Should be: "SELECT COUNT(ForumPost.Id) AS PostCount, COUNT(ForumPost.ThreadId)AS ThreadCount FROM ForumPost WHERE UserName = @UserName;"

Answer (score 0):

Just do

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ForumPost WHERE UserName = @UserName;